# Why is this spacing inconsistent?

Tags: spacing

As you can see, the field `"xyz"` has a larger space above and below it. How would I rectify this?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
               \begin{large}
                    \textbf{Title}\\
                    Name\\
                    xyz\\
                    Supervisor\\
                    Date of Submission
                \end{large}
```

Comment: It is because of something in your code that you do not disclose.

Comment: presumably something like `{\large Supervisor\\ Date of Submussion}` which causes this text to have the line spacing of the outside text.

Comment: Added my code to the comment

Comment: Since you're presumably under `\centering` (maybe because of an enclosing `center` environment), just adding ``\\`` after `Date of Submission` is sufficient.